# Как найти в массиве чисел два нуля, между которыми другое число?

Tags: javascript

Дан массив целых чисел. Нужно найти в массиве два елемента, содержащие 0, между которыми находится один элемент, содержащий не 0. Ну и вернуть индекс этих элементов.

При этом не использовать foreach, filter, some или другие "умные" методы.

Comment: добавь пример массива и ожидаемый результат

Comment: В чём проблема "умных" методов?

Comment: Используйте простой цикл for. Что не получается?

Comment: Похожа на задачку с собеседования, на минимизацию сложности. Хотелось бы увидеть ваш вариант (попытки, хоть и не работающие). Пока голосу за закрытие, т. к. такового нет.

Comment: Кто-нибудь может мне объяснить почему закрывают вопросы, после того как автор выбрал правильное решение?

Comment: Читая вопрос напрашивается, что в массиве должны встречаться числа **ноль**, а не числа, содержащие цифру ноль. Поэтому я за [такое решение](http://opan.strana.de/stack/dva-nulya.html). (см. исходный код)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот моё решение. Надеюсь помог^-^

```js
var array = [103, 23, 012, 1034, 2305, 679, 3120];
var result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 2; i++) {
  if (array[i].toString().includes('0') &&
    !array[i + 1].toString().includes('0') &&
    array[i + 2].toString().includes('0')) {
    result.push(array[i] + ' ' + array[i + 1] + ' ' + array[i + 2]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Кто против даного решение? Приглашаю его обсудить что ему не нравится

Comment: Судя по "задаче" `При этом не использовать foreach, filter, some или другие "умные" методы.` фишка с `includes` не прокатит. Я так понимаю этот ньюанс написан из-за того, что не нужны лишние проходы по массиву (что есть внутри каждого из этих методов). Метод `includes` - тоже таковым является. А у вас он еще и на каждой итерации по 3 раза

Comment: Я не знаю насчет includes, то ли "умный", то ли нет.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, в данном случае `includes` - это не метод массива

Comment: @ПростаMiha Я уже привык что просто так без объяснения ставят минусы, такое ощущение, что это делают чтобы получить ачивку за поставленный минус :) Я вам потсавлю +1 для справделивости)

Comment: @Grundy внутри `String.includes` юзается `String.indexOf`. А втнутри `String.indexOf` есть проход по this как по массиву через `while`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, как это противоречит утверждению, что _в данном случае `includes` - это не метод массива_?